# url returning none in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am running a website with python and Django . I have made all changes that are required to run.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url('index.html', views.index, name='index'),
url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url('', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
url('dashboard', views.obs_index, name='admin_dash'),
url('halls/active', views.obs_halls_active, name='active-halls'),
url('halls/pending', views.obs_halls_pending, name='pending-halls')
]
```

obs_index.html:

```
{% block bookings %}
  <li>
    <a href="javaScript:void();" class="waves-effect">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
      <span>Bookings</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
        <li><a href="{% url 'obsadmin:bookings_user' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> By Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'obsadmin:bookings_owner' %}"><i class="zmdi zmdi-star-outline"></i> By Owners</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endblock %}
```

When i run and click on the bookings menu, it is not working.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^index/$, views.index, name='index')]
```

you have to change your url patterns this way, or for newer versions

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='index')]
```

Comment: Thank u for the reply . The error is in last 2 urls given above.

Comment: you have to use any of the paterns i showed above for all urls depending on your django version